# Manually inserting new lines in PHP string

Tags: php, html

I have some user submitted data that comes from a `<textarea>`.  I then have some code that inserts a comment above it.  Kind of like this....

```
$my_comment = 'stuff from me';
$user_comment = $_POST['user_comment'];
$full_comment = $my_comment . '\n\n' . $user_comment;
```

After this, `$full_comment` gets inserted into the DB.  Later, it gets pulled from the DB and put into a `<textarea>`.  I want the `\n\n` to actually function like new lines, but instead they actually show as "\n\n" in the new `<textarea>`.

**How can I make the `\n\n` function correctly?**

BTW, I already know about form validation, PDO, etc.  This is just example code.

Comment: If you use single quotes it won't be interpreted correctly. Use double quotes: `"\n\n"`

Comment: That was it @ishegg!  Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using `\n`, why don't you go with the official PHP end of line? `$full_comment = $my_comment . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . $user_comment;`

Comment: @AlejandroIván depends on the use case, a browser for example will collapse the newline (unless you wrap the code in `<pre>` tags) so it's no use (buena weón!)

Comment: @ishegg right, but on textarea I’m not sure if it actually works that way (weeena!)

Comment: @AlejandroIván you're completely right, I stopped reading after '\n\n' lol, `PHP_EOL` definitely does work as intended inside `textarea`

Comment: Didn't know about `PHP_EOL`.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @ishegg: Want to post a quick answer so you can get credit?

Comment: No worries man, I'm not here for the points :). In fact, since people here love to downvote everything, maybe you can delete your question? Since your problem is resolved. Good luck!

Comment: I'm actually going to leave it b/c it is, in fact, not a duplicate.  This would be valuable for people who don't know about the single vs. double quote thing for `\n`.  The claimed duplicate is someone specifically asking if you can single quote it.  Thx for posting your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `htmlentities` functions.

```
$full_comment = $my_comment . '\n\n' . $user_comment;
$full_comment =  htmlentities( $full_comment );
```

also 
    stripslashes can be used to strip slashed if necessary

```
$full_comment =  stripslashes( htmlentities( $full_comment ) );
```